# How to get currencies from rest coutries API v3.1 using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, rest

[image]

[image]

```
@foreach ($responseBody as $response)
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">Official Name</div>
    <div class="col-8">{{$response->name->official}}</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-4">Currencies</div>
   <div class="col-8">{{ $response->currencies???? }}</div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

I using Laravel to consume API from https://restcountries.com/. I success to get Name of the country, but I still failed to get the currencies. The "SGD" code is different for each country.
How to get the name of currencies?

Comment: it might be a lot easier if you use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http::get("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/{$name}")->json();  .. which will returning same country data but in plain simple good old "array" , but still you need to run foreach loop to process the "currencies" as some country might have multiple currencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run another loop for the currencies:

```
@foreach($response->currencies as $id => $info)
    <b>{{ $id }}</b>: {{ $info->name }} {{ $info->symbol }}
@endforeach
```